# jenkins GUI Tests on windows

Tags: jenkins

I have a windows machine and a sample maven(swing) project. I want to perform the following actions :

1. mvn -B -DskipTests clean package
2. mvn test

I am running jenkins using 'java -jar jenkins.war'

I am able to build successfully, but when GUI tests are run, I can see a java launch for a fraction of seconds in my taskbar, but no window opens up and eventually, GUI tests fail.

I am new to Jenkins, would really appreciate help on this.

Thanks in advance